# ODE, Picard approximation of a second order equation: How do I make sure that this is correct.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, numerical-methods

I have the following problem: $$\ddot{x} + \dot{x}^2-2x=0$$ and I.V are: $x(0)=1 \qquad$ $\dot{x}(0) = 0$. and I need to find two first "Picard" approximations.
I first arranged it in the form $\cases{{\dot{x}=y}\\{\dot{y}=-y^2+2x}}$. Now, first step: $\left(\begin{matrix} x_0(t)\\y_0(t)
\end{matrix}\right) =
 \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$.

 Second step 
$\left(\begin{matrix} x_1(t)\\y_1(t)
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) + \displaystyle{\int_0^t \left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 2 \end{matrix}\right)ds}
 = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 2t \end{matrix}\right)$.
Third step: 
$\left(\begin{matrix} x_2(t)\\y_2(t)
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) + \displaystyle{\int_0^t \left(\begin{matrix}2s\\ -4s^2+2 \end{matrix}\right)ds}
 = \left(\begin{matrix}1+t^2\\ 2t - \frac{4}{3}t^3 \end{matrix}\right)$
I need an approval that this is the right way to go. If not - It'll be very kind of you to show me how it should be done.

Comment: Looks right. Note only that $x_{n}(t)$ fails to converge to the solution when $n \to \infty$ if $t$ is large, seems to be $t > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what is expected, but a different method which allows to compare the respective results.

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2-2x=0$$
This is an autonomous ODE. So, the change of function is  $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=f'f$
$$f'f+f^2=2x$$
With $F(x)=f(x)^2$ :
$$F'+2F=4x$$
$$F=c_1e^{-2x}+2x-1$$
$f=\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{c_1e^{-2x}+2x-1}$
$$t=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c_1e^{-2x}+2x-1}}$$
If the initial point is $(x_0 , t_0)$ :
$$t=t_0+\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{c_1e^{-2\chi}+2\chi-1}}$$
Since there is no closed form for this integral, further calculus have to be carried out with numerical integration, or with limited series expension and approximates.